# Script to set dynamic image ratio breaks when cache refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, caching

I created [this script](https://codepen.io/nopain_nogluten/pen/aRqpOy). It allows me to create 2 kinds of image ratios, in terms of their original size. It works on CodePen and in local, but when I reload the cache it generally doesn't work and I don't know why. I think it's linked to the loading time of the images.

Here is an example without my cache refreshed (it works) : [Working grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6NKs.png)

Here is another with the cache refreshed : [Not working grid : all the images got the same width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9BWF.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].clientWidth >= x[i].clientHeight) {
      x[i].parentElement.style.width = "23%";
      x[i].style.width = "100%";
    } else {
      x[i].parentElement.style.width = "10%";
      x[i].style.width = "100%";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.cards {
  margin-left: 5vw;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-right: 5vw;
  width: 90vw;
}

.workzone {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

main div div {
  height: 15vh;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cards div::after {
  content: "";
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="cards">
  <div class="workzone">
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/3150x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/3150x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x1150"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/3150x450"></div>
    <div><img class="card" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x4150"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nopain_nogluten/pen/aRqpOy)

Thanks for your help